# Align elements to the center of another element

Tags: html, css, element

This is my html:

```css
.HCSI {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: ;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.home,
.csgo,
.steam,
.info {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float: center;
}
.home:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 1);
}
.HCSI,
li {
  color: #000;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  word-spacing: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>VusicVoid</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="HCSI">
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <li class="home">Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/">
        <li class="csgo">Csgo</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="steam">Steam</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="info">Info</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you put these in a code tester, there should be 4 blue boxes inside of a white one but my problem is I can't get all 4 boxes to align with the center of the white one. I'm trying to get the padding on all sides of the blue boxes to be the same.

Comment: centered vertically or horizintally?

Comment: Dear @Vusic Void Please dont forget to accept the answer if anyone of the answer given below is right, it could be an inspiration to others

Answer (score 2):

**Just fix `text-align`**
make it `text-align:center;`

```
.HCSI {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center ;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this answer give ul  **text-align:center;**  it will make the anchors center and add **text-decoration:line-through;** to a tag that makes the line vertically centered

```css
/* styleSheet */

.HCSI {
 background-color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 text-align:;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.HCSI ul {
 padding-left: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.HCSI ul a {
 text-decoration:line-through;
}
.home, .csgo, .steam, .info {
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 0.5);
 border: 2px solid #000;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 float: center;
}
.home:hover {
 background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 1);
}
.HCSI, li {
 color: #000;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: 100;
 letter-spacing: 2.5px;
 word-spacing: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>VusicVoid</title>
<link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="HCSI">
  <ul>
    <a href="">
    <li class="home">Home</li>
    </a> <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/">
    <li class="csgo">Csgo</li>
    </a> <a href="">
    <li class="steam">Steam</li>
    </a> <a href="">
    <li class="info">Info</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Just apply the Flex container (`display: flex`) properties with Flex Justify (`justify-content: center`) and Flex Alignment (`align-items: center`) Properties.

Have a look on how I've used them in the code below:

```css
/* Parent Element (Flex Container) */
.HCSI {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center the content horizontaly */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

/* Resetting <ul> (Flex Container) */
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* <li> Styles */
ul li {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* <a> Styles */
ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* <a> Hover Styles */
ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(50, 150, 250, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="HCSI">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="csgo"><a href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/">Csgo</a></li>
    <li class="steam"><a href="">Steam</a></li>
    <li class="info"><a href="">Info</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Learn more about **[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the boxes clustered in the center with a defined gap this will do the trick

```
.HCSI ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.HCSI ul a {
  /* Adjust this value to adjust the spacing around the buttons */
  padding: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

If you want the boxes spread across the bar evenly then you could add this instead

```
.HCSI ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.HCSI ul a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```